# Ingresar datos con arreglos de distinto tamaño

Tags: c++, array, vectores

Tengo una funcion que convierte los elementos ocupados de un gran arreglo con datos dispersos (hashmap) a un array. Lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente: pasar de tabla[NULL, dato, dato, NULL, NULL, dato] a un arreglo donde tenga [dato,dato,dato,dato]. El problema para hacer esto es el distinto tamaño de ambas, tabla tiene aprox 100.000 espacios, y arreglo solo la cantidad de DATOS que tiene tabla. Al hacer el for la diferencia de tamaños no me deja lograr lo que quiero. Como puedo hacerlo??

```
template <class K, class T>
void HashMap<K,T>::hashToArreglo(){

string arreglo [getPalabrasDiferentes()]; //getPalabrasDiferentes es la cantidad de DATOS que tiene tabla


for (int i=0;i<tamanio;i++){
   if(tabla[i]!=NULL){
   arreglo[i]=tabla[i]->getClave();  //getClave accede al dato de tabla
   }
}


for (int i=0;i<getPalabrasDiferentes();i++){
   cout<<arreglo[i]<<endl;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

un array tal que:

```
int array[100];
```

Tiene varios problemas:

- Su tamaño, de acuerdo al estándar, debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación, es decir, el tamaño debe ser **constante** y conocido por el compilador. Tu caso no cumple esta condición ya que el tamaño del array viene dado por una variable
- Los arrays se almacenan **en la pila** del programa. Una región bastante limitada en cuanto a tamaño. No te interesa almacenar arrays grandes en la pila o corres el riesgo de que tu programa muera de forma prematura.

Para afrontar problemas como el que nos ocupa tienes que usar memoria dinámica:

```
string * arreglo = new string[getPalabrasDiferentes()];
```

La diferencia está en que ahora el array se encuentra en el *heap*. Una región de memoria que es tan grande como la memoria de la que disponga tu equipo. Aquí puedes almacenar *sin problemas* las colecciones que quieras sin preocuparte por su tamaño.

Para añadir elementos al arreglo, dado que ahora el índice de `tabla` no se corresponde con el de `arreglo`, tienes que usar **dos índices**

```
for (int i=0, j=0; i<tamanio; i++)
{
    if (tabla[i] != nullptr)
    {
        arreglo[j] = tabla[i]->getClave();
        j++;
    }
}
```

Una mejora sería usar un contenedor como `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<string> arreglo;

// Este paso no es imprescindible
// pero si mejora los tiempos de ejecución ya que el objeto no tendra
// que redimensionar varias veces el array interno que gestiona
arreglo.reserve(getPalabrasDiferentes());

for (int i=0; i<tamanio; i++)
{
    if (tabla[i] != nullptr)
    {
        arreglo.push_back(tabla[i]->getClave());
    }
}
```